# How can I add markers to implicit_plot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, maxima

The plot is generated by the following commands in Maxima. How can I add dots / markers at given coordinates?

```
load(implicit_plot);
ip_grid_in:[15,15]$
implicit_plot ([x^2 = y^3 - 3*y + 1, y=x^2], [x, -4, 4], [y, -4, 4], 
           [gnuplot_preamble, "set zeroaxis"]);
```

I have tried adding `[discrete, [[1.0,1.0], [1.0, 2.0]]]` to the list of equations but apperantly `implicit_plot` cannot handle it (perhaps because it is not an equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no maxima wizard, but in gnuplot, I would add points using `set label`.

```
set label 1 at 1,1 point
set label 2 at 1,2 point
```

Based on what you have above, I would think you could just add this to the preamble:

```
implicit_plot ([x^2 = y^3 - 3*y + 1, y=x^2], [x, -4, 4], [y, -4, 4], 
       [gnuplot_preamble, "set zeroaxis;set label 1 at 1,1 point;set label 2 at 1,2 point"]);
```

It's a bit ugly, but I'm betting that it works :)

Of course, you may need to `unset` those labels in a later preamble if maxima re-uses the same gnuplot instance and doesn't issue a `reset` implicitly:

```
unset label 1; unset label 2
```

There are lots of things you can do to customize the appearance of the points (color, point-type, etc).  in gnuplot, `help label` should discuss a bunch of those options if you're interested.

Comment: Upvoted, it works and acceptable as a workaround. The problem is that I have a bunch of datapoints that should be plotted along with the implicit function, making the gnu_plot preamble *VERY LONG*. Well, unless I hit some built in limit for the length of a line, it could work.

Comment: OK, I will post a new question if it doesn't work out. Thanks!